# How to parse list from a list of data json in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue parsing my `jsonData` in flutter.  This is my json.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "02ab1ef0-6fa9-11ea-ba0f-b1d475e9cef4",
            "policy_name": "Third Party Insurance",
            "description": "This is Third Party Insurance",
            "status": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-26 21:30:27",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-26 21:30:27",
            "insurance_policy_type": [
                {
                    "id": "3c674550-6faa-11ea-b97c-9d7c2598dab0",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "02ab1ef0-6fa9-11ea-ba0f-b1d475e9cef4",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Third Party - Grade A",
                    "description": "Third Party - Grade A. Third Party - Grade A. Third Party - Grade A",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Third Party - Grade A. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 5000,
                    "commission": 300,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 21:39:13",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 21:39:13"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4ec7a4a0-6faa-11ea-9739-77f0ed3fc12c",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "02ab1ef0-6fa9-11ea-ba0f-b1d475e9cef4",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Third Party - Grade B",
                    "description": "Third Party - Grade B. Third Party - Grade B. Third Party - Grade B",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Third Party - Grade B. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 8000,
                    "commission": 500,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 21:39:44",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 21:39:44"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "10e31df0-6fa9-11ea-962f-e5df8d00bea3",
            "policy_name": "Personal Accident Insurance",
            "description": "This is Personal Accident Insurance",
            "status": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-26 21:30:51",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-26 21:30:51",
            "insurance_policy_type": [
                {
                    "id": "aaf3ef10-6fb2-11ea-8c17-8de2cd67bf64",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "10e31df0-6fa9-11ea-962f-e5df8d00bea3",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Personal Accident - Grade A",
                    "description": "Personal Accident - Grade A. Personal Accident - Grade A. Personal Accident - Grade A",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Personal Accident - Grade A. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 4000,
                    "commission": 500,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:39:35",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:39:35"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b4835d00-6fb2-11ea-a48f-c3481acd8970",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "10e31df0-6fa9-11ea-962f-e5df8d00bea3",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Personal Accident - Grade B",
                    "description": "Personal Accident - Grade B. Personal Accident - Grade B. Personal Accident - Grade B",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Personal Accident - Grade B. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 4000,
                    "commission": 500,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:39:51",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:39:51"
                },
                {
                    "id": "c6d84e60-6fb2-11ea-a773-497e66c9ab29",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "10e31df0-6fa9-11ea-962f-e5df8d00bea3",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Personal Accident - Grade C",
                    "description": "Personal Accident - Grade C. Personal Accident - Grade C. Personal Accident - Grade C",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Personal Accident - Grade C. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 10000,
                    "commission": 1000,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:40:21",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:40:21"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1a727fc0-6fa9-11ea-a43f-b52dc75efa00",
            "policy_name": "Household Insurance",
            "description": "This is Household Insurance",
            "status": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-26 21:31:07",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-26 21:34:17",
            "insurance_policy_type": [
                {
                    "id": "016fa680-6fb3-11ea-93b7-3fdae3d5875a",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "1a727fc0-6fa9-11ea-a43f-b52dc75efa00",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Household Insurance - Grade D",
                    "description": "Household Insurance - Grade D. Household Insurance - Grade D. Household Insurance - Grade D",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Household Insurance - Grade D. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 9000,
                    "commission": 1000,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:42:00",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:42:00"
                },
                {
                    "id": "13a62720-6fb3-11ea-8842-ed9732bb7c86",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "1a727fc0-6fa9-11ea-a43f-b52dc75efa00",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Household Insurance - Grade K",
                    "description": "Household Insurance - Grade K. Household Insurance - Grade K. Household Insurance - Grade K",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Household Insurance - Grade K. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 7500,
                    "commission": 600,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:42:30",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:42:30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f4ceb490-6fb2-11ea-9b04-a1229a2e2128",
                    "insurance_policy_id": "1a727fc0-6fa9-11ea-a43f-b52dc75efa00",
                    "insurance_company_id": "07a53f10-6fa8-11ea-bb6d-89fb742a644e",
                    "policy_type_name": "Household Insurance - Grade C",
                    "description": "Household Insurance - Grade C. Household Insurance - Grade C. Household Insurance - Grade C",
                    "benefit": "Benefit of Household Insurance - Grade C. This is going to be a long text",
                    "amount": 9000,
                    "commission": 1000,
                    "status": 1,
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-03-26 22:41:39",
                    "updated_at": "2020-03-26 22:41:39"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have generated a model for this data which works perfectly.

```
class Insurance {
  String status;
  List<Data> data;

  Insurance({this.status, this.data});

  Insurance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String id;
  String policyName;
  String description;
  int status;
  var deletedAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  List<InsurancePolicyType> insurancePolicyType;

  Data(
      {this.id,
        this.policyName,
        this.description,
        this.status,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.insurancePolicyType});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    policyName = json['policy_name'];
    description = json['description'];
    status = json['status'];
    deletedAt = json['deleted_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    if (json['insurance_policy_type'] != null) {
      insurancePolicyType = new List<InsurancePolicyType>();
      json['insurance_policy_type'].forEach((v) {
        insurancePolicyType.add(new InsurancePolicyType.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['policy_name'] = this.policyName;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['deleted_at'] = this.deletedAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    if (this.insurancePolicyType != null) {
      data['insurance_policy_type'] =
          this.insurancePolicyType.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class InsurancePolicyType {
  String id;
  String insurancePolicyId;
  String insuranceCompanyId;
  String policyTypeName;
  String description;
  String benefit;
  int amount;
  int commission;
  int status;
  Null deletedAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  InsurancePolicyType(
      {this.id,
        this.insurancePolicyId,
        this.insuranceCompanyId,
        this.policyTypeName,
        this.description,
        this.benefit,
        this.amount,
        this.commission,
        this.status,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt});

  InsurancePolicyType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    insurancePolicyId = json['insurance_policy_id'];
    insuranceCompanyId = json['insurance_company_id'];
    policyTypeName = json['policy_type_name'];
    description = json['description'];
    benefit = json['benefit'];
    amount = json['amount'];
    commission = json['commission'];
    status = json['status'];
    deletedAt = json['deleted_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['insurance_policy_id'] = this.insurancePolicyId;
    data['insurance_company_id'] = this.insuranceCompanyId;
    data['policy_type_name'] = this.policyTypeName;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['benefit'] = this.benefit;
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    data['commission'] = this.commission;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['deleted_at'] = this.deletedAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Main.dart**

```
 List<InsurancePolicyType> insurancePolicyType;
 List<Data> insuranceDataList = [];
...


insuranceDataList = List<Data>.from(
            responseJson["data"].map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)));
        for (var i = 0; i < insuranceDataList.length; i++) {
          insurancePolicyType = List<InsurancePolicyType>.from(
              responseJson["data"][i]["insurance_policy_type"].map((i) =>InsurancePolicyType.fromJson(i)));
```

So inside every index is another list which i need to save inside the InsurancePolicyType object. Thats the data am trying to fetch.
How do i fetch  `List<InsurancePolicyType> insurancePolicyType` in my code? I need to fetch that list but i have not been able to.

Comment: Fetch means in every Data insurance_policy_type list get together right?

Comment: yeah, fetching them together with all values

Comment: lease review my code to see how am trying to map the list from my Data object

Answer (score 0):

Writing getter should be fine in this case

```
class Insurance {
  String status;
  List<Data> data;

  List<InsurancePolicyType> get getAllInsurancePolicies {
    List<InsurancePolicyType> fetchedList = List();
    for (var d in data) {
      fetchedList.addAll(d.insurancePolicyType);
    }
    return fetchedList;
  }

  Insurance({this.status, this.data});

  Insurance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: please review my code to see how am trying to map the list from my Data object

Comment: am able to get insuranceList but i cannot get insurancePolicyType.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything in your models. The following solution will work:

```
  List<InsurancePolicyType> insurancePolicyType;
  List<Data> insuranceDataList;

  insuranceDataList =
      List<Data>.from(responseJson["data"].map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)));

  insurancePolicyType = insuranceDataList
      .map((insuranceData) => insuranceData.insurancePolicyType)
      .expand((type) => type)
      .toList();
```

Once you have deserialized the json data, it is easier to use the resultant objects to retrieve the insurance policy types you want. 
This solution gets all the policy types from each Data object and then flattens that list to get the desired list of policy types.

Comment: thanks. this was helpful. But how about if i want to retrieve policy types in their various blocks instead of flattening it?

Comment: remove the line:
`.expand((type) => type)` as that is what flattens the array

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this model class and directly use it. Firstly you get the complete object using this call :

```
final insurance = insuranceFromJson(jsonString);
```

Later extract the list of data from the object using the 
following:

I will show you step by step:

```
List<YourObejct(I have used the Datum as a name)> data =List();
```

later pass the response.body  to the below method:

```
final insurance = insuranceFromJson(response.body);
```

Here you get your complete Insurance object just extract the data Object using the following:

```
data = insurance.data;
```

and Later Do your desired Stuff, I have mentioned the model class below depending on your JSON you provided.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final insurance = insuranceFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Insurance insuranceFromJson(String str) => Insurance.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String insuranceToJson(Insurance data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Insurance {
    String status;
    List<Datum> data;

    Insurance({
        this.status,
        this.data,
    });

    factory Insurance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Insurance(
        status: json["status"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    String id;
    String policyName;
    String description;
    int status;
    dynamic deletedAt;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;
    List<InsurancePolicyType> insurancePolicyType;

    Datum({
        this.id,
        this.policyName,
        this.description,
        this.status,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.insurancePolicyType,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        policyName: json["policy_name"],
        description: json["description"],
        status: json["status"],
        deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        insurancePolicyType: List<InsurancePolicyType>.from(json["insurance_policy_type"].map((x) => InsurancePolicyType.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "policy_name": policyName,
        "description": description,
        "status": status,
        "deleted_at": deletedAt,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "insurance_policy_type": List<dynamic>.from(insurancePolicyType.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class InsurancePolicyType {
    String id;
    String insurancePolicyId;
    String insuranceCompanyId;
    String policyTypeName;
    String description;
    String benefit;
    int amount;
    int commission;
    int status;
    dynamic deletedAt;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;

    InsurancePolicyType({
        this.id,
        this.insurancePolicyId,
        this.insuranceCompanyId,
        this.policyTypeName,
        this.description,
        this.benefit,
        this.amount,
        this.commission,
        this.status,
        this.deletedAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    factory InsurancePolicyType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => InsurancePolicyType(
        id: json["id"],
        insurancePolicyId: json["insurance_policy_id"],
        insuranceCompanyId: json["insurance_company_id"],
        policyTypeName: json["policy_type_name"],
        description: json["description"],
        benefit: json["benefit"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        commission: json["commission"],
        status: json["status"],
        deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "insurance_policy_id": insurancePolicyId,
        "insurance_company_id": insuranceCompanyId,
        "policy_type_name": policyTypeName,
        "description": description,
        "benefit": benefit,
        "amount": amount,
        "commission": commission,
        "status": status,
        "deleted_at": deletedAt,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```